# This question was voluntarily removed by its author way top alert moderator

Tags: discussion

I think I had pretty well answered to this question

[Giving access to shared memory after child processes have already started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419159/giving-access-to-shared-memory-after-child-processes-have-already-started)

After several comments on my answer which might be not perfect but in my opinion not wrong the OP decided to delete it I don't know how to alert moderator so I post it.

Comment: To be clear, the OP deleted his whole question, not just your answer (which isn't possible). Whether someone should have the right to remove their own perfectly good answered questions could be debated, I suppose.

Comment: I was not clear in my post the OP deleted his question and my answer

Comment: As an aside, the question has been undeleted.

Comment: @Wooble: Had the single answer posted to that question gotten an upvote, it probably would have prevented deletion of the question. Upvotes on the answers demonstrate community interest, and give the answerers a vested interest (loss of rep if the question is deleted).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting the question here is about your only way to address a deleted post if you don't have 10K+ rep.  If the post has been deleted by the owner then you're not likely to get much further with it.

If there is something specifically offensive or it otherwise truly needs moderator attention then that's one thing.  If you're just miffed that the post got deleted then it's best to just get over it and move on.

Comment: `Posting the question here is about your only way to address a deleted post...` That's not entirely true. He still has to option to flag *another* question or answer of that user for Moderator Attention and explain what he needs. Though, coming here is in *this* case most likely the better option (feedback and such).

Answer (score 5):

I'm the author of the post in question.

The reason I deleted the post was, due to no one's fault but my own, I found that I had to repeatedly clarify my question in comments. After numerous edits I eventually decided it was better to delete it, then take a step back and work out what exactly I'm trying to solve before re-posting a better framed question. (The tipping point was when the post was automatically converted to a community wiki!)

@Xavier I do appreciate the effort you made in answering and updating several times. However, the answer doesn't yet address my problem. My apologies if I did not express my requirements clearly enough.

Comment: You should be aware that the question has been undeleted. So if it still needs to be cleaned up or really deleted flag it for a moderator.

Comment: A good answer was posted after the question was undeleted, so I'm glad. I'll leave the question as is for now to see if I can get more input from the community. Once it's solved, I'll probably rephrase the question to something more succinct for future viewers.

Comment: In fact I was as interested by how you found your answer as my answer so I'm glad it was undeleted

Comment: I've posted the solution I eventually came up with along with some examples as a new answer. Feel free to have a look and comment on it as you see fit. And thanks again for trying to help!